# Left outer join not showing unmatched pairs Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this, let's call it main

| location | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| l1 | item1 | 3.00 |
| l1 | item2 | 1.00 |
| l2 | item1 | 3.00 |
| l2 | item2 | 1.50 |
| l2 | item3 | 2.00 |
| l3 | item4 | 5.00 |
| l3 | item5 | 5.00 |

and a separate table, call it items

| items |
| --- |
| item 1 |
| item 2 |
| item 3 |
| item 5 |
| item 4 |
| item 5 |
| item 6 |

and am currently trying to join the two together with this

```
with main as (subquery to create main), 
     items as (select distinct items from main)
select i.items, m.*
from items i 
left join main m on i.items = m.items
order by m.location, i.items
```

And my desired result is

| i.items | location | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | l1 | item1 | 3.00 |
| item2 | l1 | item2 | 1.00 |
| item3 | l1 | null | null |
| item4 | l1 | null | null |
| item5 | l1 | null | null |
| item6 | l1 | null | null |
| item1 | l2 | item1 | 3.00 |
| item2 | l2 | item2 | 1.50 |
| item3 | l2 | item3 | 2.00 |
| item4 | l2 | null | null |
| item5 | l2 | null | null |
| item6 | l2 | null | null |
| item1 | l3 | null | null |
| item2 | l3 | null | null |
| item3 | l3 | null | null |
| item4 | l3 | item4 | 5.00 |
| item5 | l3 | item5 | 5.00 |
| item6 | l3 | null | null |

However, it ends up just looking like the main table but sorted, with none of the unmatched items being shown. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Giuseppe my understanding was that left join ensures every item from the left table is present, matched or not. What would I need to do to get the desired result?

Comment: And every item from the left table *is* present. Look at the first column: all items are there. What you want instead is to have all combinations of items and locations and keep these when joining the main table. Please see my answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want one result row per item and location whether or not that pair has entries in the main table. So first generate these rows with a cross join. Only then outer join your original data.

```
with main as (<subquery to create main>), 
     items as (select distinct item from main),
     locations as (select distinct location from main)
select i.item, l.location, m.price
from items i 
cross join locations l
left join main m on m.item = i.item and m.location = l.location
order by i.item, l.location;
```

Comment: I tried this but am now getting a massive number of results with several repeats. The goal is to show the price of each item at each location, regardless of whether or not it is actually sold there. In my example, item 6 is not sold anywhere, but it still will show on the furthest left column with null as the price.

Comment: I don't follow. The query should give you exactly one result row per item and location. So with, say, ten items and six locations you'd get sixty rows. Is this not what you want? And if item #6 ain't sold anywhere, it is not in the main table, so where do you want to get it from then to show it in your result?

Comment: The point of the query is to be able to compare pricing on items, and see if any locations are missing pricing on an item. So if it's not on the main table, I want it to show up so I am able to see that location needs a price for whatever item. My table has 81 locations and 83 items, when running the above I get about 262,000 results. If i specify distinct, it goes down to 3200ish

Comment: Then your main table is different from what you are showing. 81 x 83 make 6723 rows, not 262000. This means you have more than one row for the same location and item in your main table. In that case: What price do you want to show? The lowest? The highest? The average price? ...

Comment: the goal is to show all of the pricing for each location. I believe the issue I had was that my table had a couple more fields that were interfering. I simply concatenated these into one field and it seems to be working now. Thank you.